# Get value from number

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have a number in this format:

```
3 320,17
```

And I need to get it like:

```
3320,17
```

if I use:

```
floatval($price)
```

it only return the number 3 separated by the space.

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: So where are we with this question now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just replace the space and the comma in your number with `str_replace()`

```
echo (float) str_replace([" ", ","], ["", "."], $str);
```

output:

```
3320.17
```

To get your float number now in your expected format just use `number_format()`.

```
$str = "3 320,17";
$floatNumber = (float)str_replace([" ", ","], ["", "."], $str);//Create valid float number
echo number_format($floatNumber, 2, ",", "");
```

Comment: Had just written almost word-for-word the same answer, though I used `preg_replace`

Comment: Just an FYI this only works in `php 4 +`, otherwise use `array()`.

Comment: @BeatAlex You mean in other words: The code works for everyone who lives in 2015 and if your from the past you have to use the old syntax `array()` ?! :)

Comment: Yeah, something like that!